# how to use isolates with a whole class not just a starting point function

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart-isolates

I want to create a second thread to host and multiple functions as well as to accept and output messages and data. I tried googling a lot but most examples are either straight copy paste of each other or very low level tutorials.

Comment: is it related to your previous question? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink it is related, I am trying to add some parallelism in my app when dealing with the refreshes of the UI when the streams have new values. i think putting the streams and their data in a separate isolate would help with the performance issues.

Comment: isolates are useful when you have a looooong running task that otherwise would block main isolate thread, your case is different i suppose?

Comment: @pskink yeah a little off my needs right now, but I will need it in the very near future since I am adding more features to my app and that would clutter the main thread even more